# Spring request validation not working

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, controller

We are trying to do input validation for requests using spring. We followed this tutorial: http://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/ but it doesn't seem to work. Looks like the `@NotNull` and / or  `@Valid` are ignored for some reason.

For example, we have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public void test(@RequestBody @Valid TestDTO testDTO, BindingResult result) {

   this.validateDTO(result);
}


protected void validateDTO(BindingResult result) {

if (result.hasErrors()) {
    List<FieldError> fieldErrors = result.getFieldErrors();

    throw new FieldValidationException(fieldErrors);
  }
}
```

TestDTO is the following class:

```
public class TestDTO {

    @NotNull
    private String test;
...
}
```

So we expect, that when POSTing a request without the `test` field, `FieldValidationException` will be thrown. However, this does not happen because `result.hasErrors()` = false for some reason.

Anyone know why this happens? And how to fix it?

**EDIT:** We tried to add to validator bean to our xml:

```
<beans:bean id="validator"
        class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

But now we get the following exception we we start the server: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/ValidatorFactory`.
We have the following gradle dependencies, to my understanding these versions **should** be compatible:

```
compile group:'javax.validation', name:'validation-api', version:'1.1.0.Final'
compile group:'org.hibernate', name:'hibernate-validator', version:'5.2.2.Final'
```

Comment: have you enabled mvc annotion driven?`<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Comment: Do you have web mvc enabled and do you have a validator implementation on your classpath (not only the api)!

Comment: yes, annotation-driven is enabled. We have the hibernate-validator if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks annotation @Valid should be before @RequestBody

Comment: Tried it, but I still get result.hasErrors() = false :(

Comment: What is inside of your testDTO object when you post it? Is test field null?

Comment: yes, I just use Chrome Poster, and post an empty JSON {}

Comment: If I understood you correctly it didn't look like that: {test:""}? Perhaps you should try to post it with empty fields that you want to validate. Also you didn't answer my question about what is inside testDTO object (I mean what values have fields that you are trying to validate in your post method).

Comment: I don't understand your question - as I said, I posted an empty JSON, like so: {}. If I post something like this {"test" : ""}, then the test field isn't null (it's ""), so it should be valid anyway.

Comment: I mean have you checked in your debuger what testDTO object contains. Like breakpoint on this.validateDTO(result) line and hovering over  testDTO in your declaration. I suspect that this object could contain some values that prevent your validation.

Comment: Ah, ok :) - I debugged it now and I get test = null when I post {}